# Google Play Store Submit Update button disabled after making changes

Tags: android, firefox, google-play

I'm trying to provide more information about a build for the Store Listing.

I've just made a change to the `Full description` field, and the `Submit Update` button is still disabled. I've tried changing other required fields also, to no avail.

[image]

Here is some information about the state and environment:

- I've already successfully uploaded an APK, which is already available for testing.
- I'm using Firefox 40.0.3 on Yosemite.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you certain all required fields are filled in? and does your new .apk have a version number and version code that are greater than your currently uploaded APK?

Comment: Yes, all required fields are filled in, and the version code and version name are correct. I know all this for certain, because the APK is already uploaded successfully, so it passed all validation. There are no empty fields.

Comment: I have the same problem. Both my apps have the button disabled. I'm using Chrome. One is in version 1.1 another 1.3 (updated last May). On my Alert panel I have "Looks like everything is going well". any idea?

Answer (score 7):

If your release is still in Alpha or Beta testing phase,

1. from the Google Play Console Dashboard, select your app.

   on the sidebar, select "Release management"

   and "App releases"

   Then choose "Manage Alpha" or "Manage Beta."

   Click the "Create Release" button, and follow the prompts.

.

Answer (score 2):

The procedure has changed a little bit.
You have to proceed the next steps:

1. Go to: Release management (from the menu on the left) ->
2. App releases ->
3. Upload the APK here and supply it with the release name and notes ->
4. Save and publish

Answer (score 0):

Clear browser history, Or Use another browser

Comment: Please describe your answer by saying how to clear browser history.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it happen to me just now well you Just Refresh the Page.  and all will be well :)

Comment: Works for me too! Amazing.